# SL4J setup with spring webapp using tomcat not logging?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, slf4j

I'm stuck in a loop and cant quite figure out why when my war is deployed to tomcat there is no output logs - however if i run unit tests locally through intellij the log file is populated as expected.

Web.xml contains:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>logbackConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/logback.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

src/main/java/resources/logback.xml (also have it in web-inf/logback.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<appender name="FILE-AUDIT"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>storagedebug.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>storagedebug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>

</appender>

<logger name="com.app.storage" level="debug"
        additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
</logger>

<root level="error">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
</root>

</configuration>
```

Finally relevant dependencies:

```
compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.7'
compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'jcl-over-slf4j', version: '1.7.25'
compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-core', version:'1.1.2'
compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', 
version:'1.1.2'
```

And i have included the following with my spring dependencies:

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: "commons-logging", module: "commons-logging"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For `<file>storagedebug.log</file>` can you try putting absolute path for log file? Since at present,this is relative to tomcat bin directory. Also don't forget to update absolute path at `<fileNamePattern>storagedebug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log` also

Comment: No difference there.